Do the angels ascending and descending on Jacob's Ladder in Genesis 28:12 represent the holy elect replacing Satan and his demons?
Genesis 28:10-15

Jacob left Beersheba and set out for Harran. When he reached a certain
place, he stopped for the night because the sun had set. Taking one of
the stones there, he put it under his head and lay down to sleep.
He had a dream in which he saw a stairway resting on the earth, with its top reaching to heaven, and the angels of God were ascending and
descending on it.
There above it stood YHWH, and he said: “I am YHWH,
the God of your father Abraham and the God of Isaac. I will give you
and your descendants the land on which you are lying. Your descendants
will be like the dust of the earth, and you will spread out to the
west and to the east, to the north and to the south. All peoples on
earth will be blessed through you and your offspring. I am with you
and will watch over you wherever you go, and I will bring you back to
this land. I will not leave you until I have done what I have promised
you.”

Romans 11:11-24

Again I ask: Did they stumble so as to fall beyond recovery? Not at
all! Rather, because of their transgression, salvation has come to the
Gentiles to make Israel envious. But if their transgression means
riches for the world, and their loss means riches for the Gentiles,
how much greater riches will their full inclusion bring!
I am talking to you Gentiles. Inasmuch as I am the apostle to the
Gentiles, I take pride in my ministry in the hope that I may somehow
arouse my own people to envy and save some of them. For if their
rejection brought reconciliation to the world, what will their
acceptance be but life from the dead? If the part of the dough
offered as firstfruits is holy, then the whole batch is holy; if the
root is holy, so are the branches.
If some of the branches have been broken off, and you, though a wild
olive shoot, have been grafted in among the others and now share in
the nourishing sap from the olive root, do not consider yourself to
be superior to those other branches. If you do, consider this: You do
not support the root, but the root supports you. You will say then,
“Branches were broken off so that I could be grafted in.” Granted.
But they were broken off because of unbelief, and you stand by faith.
Do not be arrogant, but tremble. For if God did not spare the
natural branches, he will not spare you either.
Consider therefore the kindness and sternness of God: sternness to
those who fell, but kindness to you, provided that you continue in his
kindness. Otherwise, you also will be cut off. And if they do not
persist in unbelief, they will be grafted in, for God is able to graft
them in again. After all, if you were cut out of an olive tree that
is wild by nature, and contrary to nature were grafted into a
cultivated olive tree, how much more readily will these, the natural
branches, be grafted into their own olive tree!

Luke 22:1-14

Jesus spoke to them again in parables, saying:  “The kingdom of heaven
is like a king who prepared a wedding banquet for his son. He sent his
servants to those who had been invited to the banquet to tell them to
come, but they refused to come.
“Then he sent some more servants and said, ‘Tell those who have been
invited that I have prepared my dinner: My oxen and fattened cattle
have been butchered, and everything is ready. Come to the wedding
banquet.’
“But they paid no attention and went off—one to his field, another to
his business. The rest seized his servants, mistreated them and killed
them. The king was enraged. He sent his army and destroyed those
murderers and burned their city.
“Then he said to his servants, ‘The wedding banquet is ready, but
those I invited did not deserve to come. So go to the street corners
and invite to the banquet anyone you find.’ So the servants went out
into the streets and gathered all the people they could find, the bad
as well as the good, and the wedding hall was filled with guests.
“But when the king came in to see the guests, he noticed a man there
who was not wearing wedding clothes. He asked, ‘How did you get in
here without wedding clothes, friend?’ The man was speechless.
“Then the king told the attendants, ‘Tie him hand and foot, and throw
him outside, into the darkness, where there will be weeping and
gnashing of teeth.’
“For many are invited, but few are chosen.”

Revelation 12:4

His tail swept down a third of the stars of heaven and cast them to
the earth. And the dragon stood before the woman who was about to give
birth, so that when she bore her child he might devour it.

A Third equals 33%; Jesus died at 33 years of age and 33 kings were defeated in Joshua's campaigns. The number 33 represents defeat of the Third from heaven, Satan and his angels.
This is barely scratching the surface. Does this evidence prove that God's chosen elect replace Satan's fallen angels in heaven, to complete God's loving family for eternity?

The answer is no, because no "replacement" is described in the text, and concept of Satan ruling over demons had not emerged yet. In fact demons are hardly mentioned in the Torah, and even then they seem to be goats or goat-idols rather than demons as we normally think of them.
Lev. 17:7

וְלֹא־יִזְבְּח֥וּ עוֹד֙ אֶת־זִבְחֵיהֶ֔ם לַשְּׂעִירִ֕ם אֲשֶׁ֛ר הֵ֥ם
זֹנִ֖ים אַחֲרֵיהֶ֑ם חֻקַּ֥ת עוֹלָ֛ם תִּֽהְיֶה־זֹּ֥את לָהֶ֖ם
לְדֹרֹתָֽם׃
that they may no longer sacrifice their sacrifices   to
the hairy [goat-demons] after whom they go whoring.   A law for the
ages shall this be for them. (Schocken
Bible)

Demonology came to the fore in Judaism after the Babylonian Exile in the intertestamental period, through literature such as Tobit and the Book of Enoch. By the time of Jesus it had advanced considerably. Before the NT - and especially prior the Book of Revelation - no author describes a situation such as the OP describes.
Conclusion: The interpretation given in the OP depends on an anachronistic reading of the text, which simply describes the activity of angels ascending and descending with no mention of Satan or demons. One may interpret the text as the OP does, but to do this one has to imagine a replacement theory that did not exist when the ancient text was written.

The simplest answer to the OP's question about the understanding of Gen 28:12 is given by Jesus Himself.

Gen 28:12 - And Jacob had a dream about a ladder that rested on the
earth with its top reaching up to heaven, and God’s angels were going
up and down the ladder.

When first discipling Nathaniel, Jesus used this incident as an explanation about His own ministry:

John 1:51 - Then He declared, “Truly, truly, I tell you, you will all
see heaven open and the angels of God ascending and descending on the
Son of Man.”

That is, Jesus opened the doorway between heaven and earth - heaven is available to sinners only via the life, ministry, death, and resurrection of Jesus, and thus, mankind's has any hope of even communicating with heaven is because of Jesus.
We see this taught in other places as well:

Heb 10:19-22 - Therefore, brothers, since we have confidence to enter the Most Holy Placed by the blood of Jesus, by the new and living way opened for us through the curtain of His body, and since we have a great priest over the house of God, let us draw near with a sincere heart in full assurance of faith, having our hearts sprinkled to cleanse us from a guilty conscience and our bodies washed with pure water.
Heb 6:19, 20 - We have this hope as an anchor for the soul, firm and secure. It enters the inner sanctuary behind the curtain, where Jesus our forerunner has entered on our behalf. He has become a high priest forever in the order of Melchizedek.

I cannot find anything in Scripture about humans becoming angels, nor anything about "replacing fallen angels", etc.
The Pulpit commentary has this to say about John 1:51 -

The dream of Jacob is manifestly referred to - the union between
heaven and earth, between God and man, which dawned like a vision of a
better time upon the old patriarchal life. That which was the dream of
a troubled night may now be the constant experience of the disciples
of the Lord. The ascension of the angelic ministers is here said to
precede their descent. This is due to the original form of the dream
of Jacob, but must be supplemented by the Lord's own statement (John
3:13), "No one hath ascended into heaven, but he that descended out of
heaven." The free access to the heart of the Father, and to the centre
of all authority in heaven and earth, is due only to those who have
come already thence, who belong to him, "who go and return as the
appearance of a flash of lightning." They ascend with the desires of
the Son of man; they descend with all the faculty needed for the
fulfilment of those desires. He, "the Son of man," is now on earth to
commence his ministry of reconciliation, and is thus now equipped with
all the powers needed for its realization.


In fact the Jacob’s replacement may have happened in reverse to what you describe. Jacob has obtained the inheritance and blessings of his father Isaac by a lie and exploitation of his twin brother who was a firstborn. So maybe this change of inheritance line of Isaak brought forward the need to replace the angels.
Jesus said “your father is a father of lies”. This could be connected to Sariel who was overseeing fallen angels according to the book of Enoch. He was fighting Jacob and gave him the name of Israel.
The second replacement of angels referred to by Jesus would be the reversal of that act of Sariel as Jesus won over him.
